# Using Inputs in Ant design Table

Tags: reactjs, antd

In my application i using [Ant design Table](https://ant.design/components/table/) my code is like below :

```
<Table size="small" dataSource={this.props.actionArray}>
            <Column title="Name" dataIndex="id" key="name"/>
            <Column title="Action" key="action"
            render={(text,record)=>(
                <span>
                    <a href="" >Edit</a>
                    <span className="ant-divider"/>
                    <a href="" >Delete</a>
                </span>
            )}
            />

        </Table>
```

i want when user click on `Edit` the entire row of table render as a [`<Input type="text"/>`](https://ant.design/components/input/) instead of normal text , so users can edit the row data, also a custom save button when user click on it call a function(ex save() )
but i don't know how to this .

Comment: There is [editable row](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-row) example in documentation, it should help you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like this. Save the editting record id in the state and according to that show or hide the input:

```js
columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    render: (text, record) =>
      record.id === this.state.editingId ? (
        <Input type="text"/>
      ) : (
        text
      ),
  },
  {
    title: "Action",
    render: (text, record) => (
      <span>
        <a href="" >Edit</a>
        <span className="ant-divider"/>
        <a href="" >Delete</a>
      </span>
    )}
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Antd has editable rows feature for antd `<Table>`

[Editable rows documentation](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-row)

App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Input, Popconfirm, Table, Typography } from "antd";

const originData = [
  {
    key: 1,
    name: `Edrward`,
    address: `London Park no. 1`
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    name: `James`,
    address: `London Park no. 2`
  }
];

const EditableCell = ({
  editing,
  dataIndex,
  title,
  inputType,
  record,
  index,
  children,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  return (
    <td {...restProps}>
      {editing ? (
        <Form.Item
          name={dataIndex}
          style={{
            margin: 0
          }}
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: `Please Input ${title}!`
            }
          ]}
        >
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </td>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [data, setData] = useState(originData);
  const [editingKey, setEditingKey] = useState("");

  const isEditing = (record) => record.key === editingKey;

  const edit = (record) => {
    form.setFieldsValue({
      name: "",
      address: "",
      ...record
    });
    setEditingKey(record.key);
  };

  const cancel = () => {
    setEditingKey("");
  };

  const save = async (key) => {
    try {
      const row = await form.validateFields();
      const newData = [...data];
      const index = newData.findIndex((item) => key === item.key);

      if (index > -1) {
        const item = newData[index];
        newData.splice(index, 1, { ...item, ...row });
        setData(newData);
        setEditingKey("");
      } else {
        newData.push(row);
        setData(newData);
        setEditingKey("");
      }
    } catch (errInfo) {
      console.log("Validate Failed:", errInfo);
    }
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      width: "25%",
      editable: true
    },
    {
      title: "Address",
      dataIndex: "address",
      width: "40%",
      editable: true
    },
    {
      title: "Action",
      dataIndex: "operation",
      render: (_, record) => {
        const editable = isEditing(record);
        return editable ? (
          <span>
            <Typography.Link
              onClick={() => save(record.key)}
              style={{
                marginRight: 8
              }}
            >
              Save
            </Typography.Link>
            <Popconfirm title="Sure to cancel?" onConfirm={cancel}>
              <a>Cancel</a>
            </Popconfirm>
          </span>
        ) : (
          <Typography.Link
            disabled={editingKey !== ""}
            onClick={() => edit(record)}
          >
            Edit
          </Typography.Link>
        );
      }
    }
  ];
  const mergedColumns = columns.map((col) => {
    if (!col.editable) {
      return col;
    }

    return {
      ...col,
      onCell: (record) => ({
        record,
        inputType: "text",
        dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
        title: col.title,
        editing: isEditing(record)
      })
    };
  });
  return (
    <Form form={form} component={false}>
      <Table
        components={{
          body: {
            cell: EditableCell
          }
        }}
        dataSource={data}
        columns={mergedColumns}
        rowClassName="editable-row"
        pagination={{
          onChange: cancel
        }}
      />
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Output:

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]